# Create scripts that run in different servers

Tags: perl, distributed, system-administration

I have three servers that are used to manage a bunch of other client servers.  One of the managing servers has nagios, the other has a web proxy, another has an ldap and MySQL server.

Whenever I need to include a new client server, I have to log into Server A, and create the SQL entry, go to nagios and create the entry, go to the web server and add the proxy. You get the picture.  What I would like is to be able have all servers share a scripts directory, say '/opt/boxes/scripts` and in there have a bunch of scripts that know where they can run.  Say I'm in server A and run script X, that should run on server B, it will actually run in server B.

Is there a simple way to do this? Preferably perl bases since that is something i know a little bit about.

Comment: How does it not fit your system to use Perl to do your networking for you? If you have to create an SQL (to do something in a database) you can use `DBI`. You can use FTP to push files around and you can even read and write from files via FTP. I use Perl to script complex network interactions all the time, and run them from one machine. You get a programmable interface to FTP, Telnet, etc.

Comment: @Axeman, I was looking for some kind of framework that facilitates this.  I have all this servers with ssh public key so doing ssh and scp is straightforward.  I was thinking that there might a different way.

Comment: the portable thing is doable. You simply need to abstract the underlying facilities. However, it's harder to catch all the bugs from running in different environments--even if only slightly different, than it is to catch the bugs in a single environment using standard networking tools. That's why I recommended it. However, if you want some similar abilities on whatever machine you're logged into, I can imagine the machine portable version makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way may be to make a directory for each script on each of the machines.

In one directory, the actual script runs.
In all the other directories, the script does a ssh to the appropriate server and runs the actual script.

E.g.

Script to add client
  ssh servera -c servera-addclient-to-sql
  ssh serverb -c serverb-addclient-to-nagios
  ssh serverc -c serverc-addclient-to-webproxy

Adding scripts that know where they run is fairly easy too.

In loose form

```
$RunWhere = "XXXX"
$ScriptName = "YYYY"

if `hostname` ne "XXXX" {ssh $RunWhere -c $Scriptname @ARGS ; exit; }
else {
Do the actual stuff
}
```

So run from anywhere, it runs locally if thats the right thing to do, otherwise does a secure shell to the right place and runs the same command there.